# HTML [Show] Code Only showing 1 of them when 2 are added?

Tags: html, show-hide

When I add the code below.

```
<a id="show_id" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='';
            document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='none';"
   class="link">
   [Show]
</a>
<span id="spoiler_id" style="display: none">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='none';
              document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='';"
     class="link">
  [Hide]
  </a>
<br>
INSERT CONTENT HERE
</span>
```

I can only get 1 of these codes to actually work when I put 2 of them into an HTML page? Any help on why this keeps happening?

Cheers,
James

Comment: You need to set different id names. Use getElementsByClassName with class name instead.

Comment: What are the IDs?

Comment: How would I change the ID then?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the second code block works, but you need to make sure that ids you use are different for both blocks. Assuming block 1 has the ids `show_id` and `spoiler_id`, and block 2 has the ids `show_id` and `spoiler_id` as well, then `document.getElementById(show_id)` will always choose the first occurence of `show_id`.

```html
<!--Code blocks. Note they both have the same IDs and getElementById-->
<!--Block 1-->
<a id="show_id" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='';
            document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='none';"
   class="link">
   [ShowBlock1]
</a>
<span id="spoiler_id" style="display: none">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='none';
              document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='';"
     class="link">
  [Hide]
  </a>
<br>
INSERT CONTENT HERE
</span>

<!--Block 2-->
<a id="show_id" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='';
            document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='none';"
   class="link">
   [ShowBlock2]
</a>
<span id="spoiler_id" style="display: none">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='none';
              document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='';"
     class="link">
  [Hide]
  </a>
<br>
INSERT CONTENT HERE
</span>
```

You should edit the IDs of block 2 to make sure it refers to itself rather than other blocks. Just change `show_id` and `spoiler_id` to something else, and change `getElementById()` accordingly. [Here's the JSFiddle for that.](https://jsfiddle.net/bL025zfu/)